# Is there a license similar to MIT that also requires changes to be indicated?

Tags: licensing, mit

The MIT License permits Commercial use, Distribution, Modification, and Private use, while requiring the inclusion of the License and copyright notice and limiting Liability and Warranty (source: https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/).

I want to add one thing: that all modifications must be indicated explicitly with date and by whom.

That way, my open software can be freely modified outside of a repository but with accountability.

Is there an existing license that offers close to these terms? Or may I simply edit the MIT License and include it in my software as "modified from the MIT License"?

Answer (score 2):

> [...]
>
> I want to add one thing: that all modifications must be indicated explicitly with date and by whom.
>
> [...]

Clause 2 of [zlib license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib_License) comes to rescue that:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib_License#Text

```
2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
   misrepresented as being the original software.
```

> ## Is there a license similar to MIT that also requires changes to be indicated?
>
> [...]
>
> Is there an existing license that offers close to these terms? [...]

Yes, there is, [zlib/libpng license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib_License)<sup>1</sup>.

> [...]
>
> [...] Or may I simply edit the MIT License and include it in my software as "modified from the MIT License"?

Best not to create any newer licenses until extremely necessary; complicates the landscape further<sup>[[Citation needed]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed)</sup>.

See also the [libpng license](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/blob/libpng16/LICENSE) in action.

<sub><sub>1: If there is a libpng license version 2 (it seems there is), I mean the classic one.</sub></sub>

Comment: Zlib only requires the version to be marked as modified. My version requires the date and by whom for each set of modified lines, so it makes modifiers accountable. I think mine is better, but I'm willing to go with Zlib. It's simpler and better, I think, than the GPLs, the CCs, and others. Thanks.

Comment: Before you go with Zlib or a custom MIT, take a deep breath and read ALv2 entirely, then read blog posts about it, then read it again. Don't rush a license decision until you are completely sure of what you want. It's better that you take your time. You don't need to add a license until you are sure of what to choose. Read the FSF and OSI guides for choosing a license.

Comment: TL;DR ALv2 grants you everything you already have in zlib/libpng license, plus (1) prevention against patent treachery and (2) a framework for nesting CLAs. Before choosing a zlib/libpng license, make sure you aren't going to need any of those two things in your use case.

Comment: Have a couple of example [ICLAs](https://apache.org/licenses/icla.pdf)/[CCLAs](https://www.apereo.org/licensing/agreements).

Comment: The examples clearly show a different use case: contributors to a large project. I'm just planning to publish unique software on github and possibly a dedicated site. These licenses are long, verbose, and oriented towards contributing to a project. I may have not explained my use case sufficiently. If anyone steals my code to patent it, I win in court, since (by definition) I published first. Zlib is great and I think anyone publishing open source code should consider it. Short, clear, and comprehensive enough (read the government advice about copyrights--it is minimal).

Comment: You haven't explained your use case at all, hence the warning against a potential misuse of MIT license. Wouldnta recommended ALv2 for a snippet, but there was no way to know, well, maybe asking. [What you describe](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8781/is-there-a-license-similar-to-mit-that-also-requires-changes-to-be-indicated/8782?noredirect=1#comment21358_8782) sounds like some middle between a small snippet and a large program potentially spawning companies and/or crude legalezes.

Comment: The Apache v2 license is very verbose as compared to MIT and Zlib licenses. Hard to understand. Worse, they are oriented toward contributors to Apache projects, which is not the typical use case for open software. We need a license that starts with MIT, then adds a prohibition on patenting and a requirement that each modification requires commenting with the author's name and the date.

Why? Because this provides a trail of accountability, should the software be taken out of its repository and used elsewhere. I don't just want to know that my program has been modified (Zlib), but specifics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98549/discussion-between-john-and-david-spector).